# Spring boot 2.4.5 REST WS WAR into glassfish 5 error in endpoint running app

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, fasterxml, glassfish-5

Hello everyone can someone help me understand why this problem occurs...

Basically I have created a REST WS with Maven and have built a WAR file to deploy into Glassfish 5 and have an error when I access one of the endpoints.

Otherwise if I deploy the same WAR into Tomcat 9, the same call to the endpoint run´s well.

The deployment process occurs with no fuss and the REST endpoints work in both.

JAVA_HOME is the same for both A.S, configured to run in Java 1.8.

But in a particular call to an endpoint this error is thrown:

```
2021-11-05 15:59:03 [http-listener-1(3)] ERROR ErrorPageFilter[forwardToErrorPage:184] - Forwarding to error page from request [/candidatos/1] due to exception [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ReferenceTypeSerializer.withResolved(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/NameTransformer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude$Include;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/ReferenceTypeSerializer;]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ReferenceTypeSerializer.withResolved(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/NameTransformer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude$Include;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/ReferenceTypeSerializer;
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ReferenceTypeSerializer.createContextual(ReferenceTypeSerializer.java:167)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.handleSecondaryContextualization(SerializerProvider.java:966)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:514)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:698)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:270)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1429)
      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:951)
      at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:454)
      at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181)
      at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
      at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
      at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
      at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<groupId>recrutamento</groupId>
<artifactId>recrutamento</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>recrutamento</name>
<description>Projeto de webservices para recrutamento</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <tomcat.version>9.0.54</tomcat.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Caso se pretenda fazer deploy deste war para outro Servidor Aplicacional -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>animal-sniffer-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
<build>
    <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/candidatos/{chave}")
public Optional<Candidato> getCandidatoID(@PathVariable("chave") Integer chave) {
    return servicoRecrutamento.getCandidatoID(chave);
}
```

**Service**

```
public Optional<Candidato> getCandidatoID(Integer chave) {
    Optional<Candidato> candidato = candidatoRepository.findById(chave);
    if(!candidato.isPresent()){
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Record with "+chave+" not found");
    }
        return candidato;
}
```

**candidatoRepository**

```
package application.entities.repositories;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import application.entities.Candidato;
@ComponentScan
@Repository
public interface CandidatoRepository extends JpaRepository<Candidato, 
 Integer>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<Candidato>{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You say that there is a difference in observed behaviour between `Tomcat` and `Glassfish`.

If we look at the log output, we will see that there is  `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` thrown.

If we looks into [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html) we can see that its thrown when ...

> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.

In practice, this occurs because some dependency versions in your app have an incompatability. You can see an example of a scenario when this can play out [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-abstractmethoderror).

If we look closer at the error message we can see the following

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ReferenceTypeSerializer.withResolved(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/NameTransformer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude$Include;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/ReferenceTypeSerializer;

So, OK ... why can it happen ? Spring Boot apps use `Jackson` for serialisation and deserialisation and typically run on an embedded `Tomcat`, which has some stuff of the right versions to enable it to work. It seems that something is very different on Glassfish, it must supply some `jars`, which cause this incompatiability.

The easiest solution seems to be to use the next version of `Glassfish`, which is 6.0 ... hopefully, it contains some more modern jars, which are compatiable with Spring Boot's jackson.

Otherwise, I think, you'll need to change the version of `Jackson` `Glassfish` v 5.0 is using ... to make it compatiable with Spring Boot.

Or change the version of `Jackson` SpringBoot is using to make it compatiable with Glasshfish version.

This gives a solution strategy.
If you still have further questions, please post in the comments to this answer.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the issue. I'll try both aproaches to solve the issue. Then i'll update this post.